# Create a copy of a file in same location as original

Tags: c#, ms-word, filepath, docx, file-rename

The end-user supplies a path, indicating where the original document is.

```
string DocxFileName = "C:\\WorksArshad\\3.docx";
```

I'd like to create a copy of the document name `3.docx` as `3Version1.docx` and store the copy in the same directory as the original.

How do I get the whole path without the file name and extension?

(i.e.) I need to get the `"C:\\WorksArshad\\"` path alone.

Comment: Use `File.Move("C:\\WorksArshad\\3.docx","C:\\WorksArshad\\test.docx")`

Comment: @Grant : Its not only the matter of renaming ,i need to store the renamed file to the specified path where the original document is stored.->

Comment: @user3611781: then make a copy. Seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: @siride: File.Copy("C:\WorksArshad\3", "C:\WorksArshad\3Version1.docx", true);   its not possible because am getting the path from user (ie)  File.Copy(fileName," ", true);

Comment: FileInfo file = new FileInfo(C:\WorksArshad\3.docx);
string path = file.Directory;  In path i would get "C:\WorksArshad"                            This is what i need huh . .I lost my rep tooo.ANGRY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Session.FileName); 
string path = file.Directory.tostring();
```

and then using

```
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Session.FileName);
        string DocxFileNamee = path + "\\" + fileName + "V1.docx";
        File.Copy(Session.FileName, DocxFileNamee, true);
```

where in **Session.FileName = "C:\WorksArshad\3.docx"** and in  **path** I'd  get "C:\WorksArshad"

requirement solved .

---

Or

```
File.Copy(Session.FileName, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Session.FileName)
, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Session.FileName)+"V1.docx"),true);
```

both the above gives the solution

Comment: i have edited your answer because it shows an exception and have updated the answer @GrantWinney